# Wrong point when barycentric coordinates in triangle add up to one

Tags: tikz-pgf, coordinates

I am trying to plot points on a triangle using areal coordinates (barycentric coordinates that add up to one). Using TikZ and the barycentric coordinate system, however, this gives the wrong point in some cases, as shown in the following example:

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage[margin=2mm,papersize={55mm,50mm}]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}                          
\noindent
\begin{tikzpicture}

\coordinate (L1) at (0:0);
\coordinate (L2) at (0:5);
\coordinate (L3) at (60:5);

\draw[thick] (L1) -- coordinate[midway](md3) (L2)
                  -- coordinate[midway](md1) (L3)
                  -- coordinate[midway](md2) (L1) -- cycle; 

\draw[very thin,dotted] (L1) -- (md1) (L2) -- (md2) (L3) -- (md3);

\fill[color=blue]  (barycentric cs:L1=8,L2=1,L3=1) circle (0.04);
\draw[color=red]   (barycentric cs:L1=0.8,L2=0.1,L3=0.1) circle (0.04);
\draw[color=green] (barycentric cs:L1=0.08,L2=0.01,L3=0.01) circle (0.04);

\fill[color=blue]  (barycentric cs:L1=1,L2=8,L3=1) circle (0.04);
\draw[color=red]   (barycentric cs:L1=0.1,L2=0.8,L3=0.1) circle (0.04);
\draw[color=green] (barycentric cs:L1=0.01,L2=0.08,L3=0.01) circle (0.04);

\fill[color=blue]  (barycentric cs:L1=1,L2=1,L3=8) circle (0.04);
\draw[color=red]   (barycentric cs:L1=0.1,L2=0.1,L3=0.8) circle (0.04);
\draw[color=green] (barycentric cs:L1=0.01,L2=0.01,L3=0.08) circle (0.04);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

which results in

[image: triangle with points using barycentric coordinates]

All points have two equal coordinates, so they should lie on the medians. When the coordinates add up to 0.1 or 10 the points plot ok, but when they add up to 1 the points are clearly wrong (and not even by the same amount if you permute the coordinates). This only happens for some points, e.g. point (0.6,0.2,0.2) plots ok.

Can someone explain why this inaccuracy appears? I have tried to understand what `\tikzdeclarecoordinatesystem{barycentric}` does in tikz.code.tex, where a division is probably to blame, but it is not clear to me.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The problem lies in fact in the `divide` (`/`) function of PGF math that is used by the `barycentric` coordinate system.

In the process of the `barycentric` coordinate system, the sum of the values is calculated which is stored in `\pgf@xb`. This sum is `10.0` in the blue case, `1.00002` in the red one and `0.09999` in the green one.

This value is then evaluated with

```
\pgfmathparse{1/\the\pgf@xb}
```

it calculates simply `1 / <sum>` for later use. With the erroneous version the results are

```
    x        1/x
10.0        0.0999
 1.00002    0.91
 0.09999   10.00099
```

The `0.91` is obviously not (nearly) correct.

The CVS version of PGF/TikZ has this fixed and the calculation results in `1.00002`.

There could be many ways to actually fix this by using TeX calculations directly *but* PGF math has a `reciprocal` function included that can be used here. If you don’t want to update to the CVS version yet (the fix for `/`/`divide` is rather big), you can use this simple fix:

```
\makeatletter
\tikzdeclarecoordinatesystem{barycentric}{{%
  \pgf@xa=0pt% point
  \pgf@ya=0pt%
  \pgf@xb=0pt% sum
  \tikz@bary@dolist#1,=,%
  \pgfmathreciprocal@{\pgf@sys@tonumber\pgf@xb}%
  \global\pgf@x=\pgfmathresult\pgf@xa%
  \global\pgf@y=\pgfmathresult\pgf@ya}}
\makeatother
```